# Netty 4.x- If use HttpObjectAggregator, do we still need to worry about LastHttpContent ?

Tags: java, http, netty

In my channel initializer I am using following 
        p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

1. Does this means I am always suppose to get full http request and there will be NO LastHttpContent/HttpContent messages will be received to my server handler ?
2. The main reason I needed to go with HttpObjectAggregator was, there was no way I could access the message body for HTTP POST requests with only having HttpServerCodec. Is there a way to do that with only having HttpServerCodec? Does anybody have a known example/blog where it correctly handled the remaining message parts in the request (i.e LastHttpContent)

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes. You'll always get `FullHttpRequest/Response`.
2. There's no way to ensure you always get `FullHttpRequest` only with `HttpServerCodec`.

On the other hand, you should never specify `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when you create an `HttpObjectAggregator`. Please specify something safer.